# Executable awk script to output its name

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have a simple executable awk script which I'm trying to make to say its own name:

```
$ cat script.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    print "Hi, I'm " ARGV[0]
}
```

when executed:

```
$ chmod u+x script.awk
$ ./script.awk
Hi, I'm awk
```

Expected (well, desired anyway) output would be `Hi, I'm script.awk`. Is there a way to achieve that except turning it to a shell script, like:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -d '' script <<EOF
BEGIN {
    print "Hi, I'm " var
}
EOF
awk -v var=$0 "$script"
```

aaand, action:

```
$ ./script.sh
Hi, I'm ./script.sh
```

Comment: Found this from Ed in this cross site dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228284/112235

Comment: Nice, thanks mate!

Comment: Lol, the James Bond effect I got: `print "Hi, I'm " ARGV[0] ENVIRON["_"]`: `Hi, I'm awk./foo.awk` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash or zsh, you can use the shell environment variable `$_` via `ENVIRON["_"]`:

```
$ cat script.awk
```

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  print "Hi, I'm " ENVIRON["_"]
}
```

```
$ chmod u+x script.awk
$ ./script.awk
Hi, I'm /tmp/./script.awk
```

The `ENVIRON` array is an [awk special variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) defined in the POSIX standard, so it should be readily available in any version of awk, but different shells implement `$_` differently, so **this is only reliable if you are invoking it from bash or zsh**.

This will *not* work in dash ([commonly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) installed as `/bin/sh`) since dash assigns the *previous* command to `$_` (if this is the first command, it will instead assign itself).

Korn Shell (ksh93, at least) prefixes the shell's PID (surrounded by asterisks) to the value, like `*12345*./script.awk`, so it needs a slight modification.

This version will work in bash, zsh, and ksh:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  self = ENVIRON["_"]
  sub(/^\*[0-9]+\*/, "", self)
  print "Hi, I'm " self
}
```

Comment: Also: I can't get `ENVIRON["$"]` to get the value of `$$` (with mawk 1.3.4), so you can't easily get the current PID. The PID might otherwise have allowed a `getline` command involving `ps -f`. You can still do it with `pstree` or `ps --forest`, but that'd be _really_ ugly and those aren't very portable.

Comment: This just printed the path to `awk` for me - tested with `gawk`, `mawk`, and `bioawk` (fork of BWK awk) on Ubuntu with `bash` shell (checked with `echo $0` as per [this tip](https://askubuntu.com/a/590902)).

Comment: That command prints a path to mawk, using mawk 1.3.4 and bash 5.1.16(1)-release (elementary OS 7, so Ubuntu 22.04) 

Comment: @jena – (My last comment was wrong and I have deleted it. You can't run this a a CLI one-liner, it must be an executable file as noted in my answer.) Writing the awk script to a file and then invoking it works for me with mawk 1.3.4 20231126 (run `mawk -W version` to compare) and zsh 5.9 (`echo $ZSH_VERSION`) or bash 5.2.21(1)-release (`echo $BASH_VERSION`). I also tried with Ubuntu 22.04 and the same versions as you have. It works fine, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRjYy.png) (press Ctrl+d to exit the `cat` after pasting).

Comment: The first time I tried putting it in the script as you show at the top and I still got a path to awk binary, not the name of the script.. 